# CREATE TABLE (MYSQL PERL)statement I use doesn't work

Tags: mysql, perl

My Code is as below. The code runs OK up to the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

use DBI;


$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:DBNAME:DatabaseHost", "DATABASE", 

"PASSWORD");


$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tt1 (
id INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
name VARCHAR(10), 
surname VARCHAR(10),
company_name VARCHAR(20),
building_number VARCHAR(4),
address VARCHAR(100),
postcode VARCHAR(6)
)");

print "table created";
```

Comment: What is the eror message?

Comment: maybe you have an error message?

Comment: Try running a plain (non-CGI) Perl script to make it easier to diagnose your problem (i.e. directly on the command line). Alternatively (even better) run the SQL directly in a MySQL console (or via phpMyAdmin if you don't have console access).

Answer (score 6):

In order to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` on a column it has to be declared as the primary key of the table.

```
$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tt1 (
id INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
name VARCHAR(10), 
surname VARCHAR(10),
company_name VARCHAR(20),
building_number VARCHAR(4),
address VARCHAR(100),
postcode VARCHAR(6)
)");
```

Comment: MANY THANKS. I was away couple of days. 'PRIMARY KEY'  worked! I was getting desperate. This was great help.